# storage API of google - want to know the API in plugin

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to export a file from local to Google cloud storage. I am importing some storage related libraries for this purpose.

```
import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage;
import com.google.api.services.storage.StorageScopes;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.Bucket;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.StorageObject;
```

I am using google plugin for eclipse to add API related libraries. But I am not able to find specific API which I need to add for the above mentioned libraries. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You can consult this [url](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/storage/v1) for the client library of the cloud storage API. Also this [one](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/java/latest/) gives you a summary of the classes related to that API and methods used inside.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're probably looking for the Cloud Storage API client library.  The JavaDoc, at least, contains the types you've listed in your question.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/storage/v1